# Verify whether point is branch point

Tags: complex-analysis, branch-points

I need to check whether $z=\infty$ is a branch point of the function $$f(z)=\sqrt[p]{(z-a_1)(z-a_2)}$$ where $p \in \mathbb{N}$ and $a_i \in \mathbb{C}$ for $i=1,2$. I know that we could make the usual change of variable $w=1/z$ and analize the case when $w=0$ to answer this question. We would thus have that:

$$f(w)=w^{-1/p}\sqrt[p]{(1-w\cdot a_1)(1-w \cdot a_2)}$$

Under this form, the right term of $f(w)$ has no branch point at $w=0$. But what about the left term? I have read a similar question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1644336/branch-point-at-infinity), but I am still not quite convinced..

Comment: The linked answer is mostly correct (except that $x = 0$ is in fact a branch point of $(1/x + 1)^{1/3}$), and you're also mostly correct :). You should get $\tilde f(w) = f(1/w) =  w^{-2/p} ((1 - a_1 w) (1 - a_2 w))^{1/p}$, then you can determine when $w = 0$ is a branch point of $w^{-2/p}$ (or you can consider $z^{2/p} ((1 - a_1/z) (1 - a_2/z))^{1/p}$ in a neighborhood of $z = \infty$).